# Need access to DocuSign from Salesforce DocuSign Admin Tab

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

We have Salesforce prod/live account, where we needed to add DocuSign.

While clicking the DocuSign tab under Saleforce tab "DocuSign Admin",
we are getting error message like this: "Sorry you do not have access to this page".

[image]

Also in the Layout Tab, adding Remote URL is not working.

[image]

If i add "Send with DocuSign" with any object like Account and click that button, it giving authentication error message like this:
[image]

Can anyone help/guide me to find out the issue and resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Got response from DocuSign Support team about this issue.

> Hi Yousuf,
>
> Welcome to the DocuSign Support Community!
>   It sounds like you have a trial DocuSign account. If that's the case, DocuSign  Services that are available for a Free Trial may not include or allow access to all features or functions.
>
> If you have further questions, please let us know.
>
> Thank you. 
>   Donna
>
> DocuSign Support Community Moderator

https://docusigncommunity.force.com/CSP_Answers?question=9061W000000boYb